# how to add primefaces to my jsp and servlets nav bar

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, servlets, primefaces

I have almost all my project in `jsp and servlets`, and now I would like to add a page which is in `primefaces` to my navigation bar...and whatever I have tried, it doesn't add it to my project...am I missing something in the `web.xml` file ? Why doesn't it show on my page when I try to add `primefaces` to my `jsp and servlets` project ? is it even possible to add `primefaces` to `jsp` ?

from `primefaces` I wanted to add `index.xhtml`, `appmenu.xhtml` and `template.xhtml`

these are my `index.html` and `navbar.jsp` that look like this...so I wanted to do something like this by adding `index.xhtml` to my nav class

index.html

```
  <ul class="nav">
           <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="assets.jsp">Assets</a></li>
           <li><a href="groups.jsp">Groups</a></li>
           <li><a href="LocationServlet">Locations</a></li>
           <li><a href="relocate.jsp">Relocate</a></li>    
           <li><a href="index.xhtml">Reports</a></li>   
   </ul>
```

So I was trying the same thing with href="index.xhtml in my navbar class

navbar.jsp

```
<ul class="nav">
        <li <c:if test="${param.pageName == 'home'}">class="active"</c:if>><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li <c:if test="${param.pageName == 'assets'}">class="active"</c:if>><a href="assets.jsp">Assets</a></li>
        <li <c:if test="${param.pageName == 'groups'}">class="active"</c:if>><a href="groups.jsp">Groups</a></li>
        <li <c:if test="${param.pageName == 'locations'}">class="active"</c:if>><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/LocationServlet">Locations</a></li>
        <li <c:if test="${param.pageName == 'relocate'}">class="active"</c:if>><a href="relocate.jsp">Relocate</a></li>
        <li <c:if test="${param.pageName == #}">class="active"</c:if>><a href="index.xhtml">Reports</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primefaces is a JSF framework so the answer is no to your question. It should be possible by adding either myfaces or mojarra JSF implementations, but then it's an ugly hybrid and not only JSP.

Also,
`<c:if test="${param.pageName == #}">` should be `<c:if test="${param.pageName == '#'}">` for the test to ever be true unless # is a variable or a typo?